# __NSCFConstantString autocapitalizationType Crash on iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6

I am developing a app which receives data from web server which shown in UITableView. When ever a user taps on any cell a new view is pushed on which I am showing a detail description in a UITextView. When back button is taped then app crashes with this error

```
[__NSCFConstantString autocapitalizationType]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10f0e8
2012-10-15 19:51:50.778 Secret[1451:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString autocapitalizationType]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10f0e8'
```

**This code is working fine on iOS 5.1 but is crashing on iOS 6**

Comment: Most likely there's something wrong with memory management, post some code?

Comment: That method appears to be part of the `UITextInputTraits` protocol and is unrelated to `NSString` and friends. Something is wired-up wrong.

Comment: Thanks.I have solved many memory leaks and still looking for more leaks. But one thing I have observed that its getting crashed only on my iPhone with iOS 6 as i borrowed two iOS 6 devices and the app is not crashing on that which is quite wired.